# Disable global routing with OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I managed to install the openvpn using the script [1] and able to connect on Mac OSX.

However, the default option is all traffic now routes thru the VPN IP.

Is it possible to route traffic using this VPN only when the destination IP is `X.X.Y.Z`?

For the rest of traffic, just use it without the VPN.

[1] https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Answer (score 12):

If you control the server then you can push specific routes by adding directives to your config file e.g.

```
push "route X.X.Y.Z 255.255.255.255"
push "route 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0"
```

You will likely also want to remove the `redirect-gateway` directive (if used).

If you want to do this on the client side then you will need to ignore the pushed routes and then configure your own by adding directives to the client config e.g.

```
route-nopull
route X.X.Y.Z 255.255.255.255
route 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

Both of which will case the specified host/network to be routed over the VPN.

Comment: What is ` 192.0.2.0`?

Comment: Good question @Ryan - it's OK to want an answer from a human being sometimes, even the answer might be quickly available through impersonal methods.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses identifies the subnet 192.0.2.0-255 as reserved for use in documentation and examples.  So it's a good choice for the example in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of this conflict with server pushed options:
https://openvpn.net/faq/overriding-a-pushed-route-in-the-clients-config-throws-an-error/

You may have an error:

```
Options error: option 'route' cannot be used in this context
```

This issue materializes because “route-nopull” option takes away the permission from the client to install server-pushed routes, effectively telling the option parser “no, this option is not valid here”.

The way to configure it correctly is then (route-nopull goes at the end):

```
...
# Options
client
route 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.128
route-metric 50
route-nopull
...
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/508451)